# C++ no known conversion from 'int*' to 'uint16_t* {a ka short unsigned int*}'

Tags: c++, arduino, stm32

I'm trying to run magnetometer code designed for Arduino on STM32. When compiling for Arduino, I get no errors and values read from sensors are signed. When compiling for STM I get error: "no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int*' to 'uint16_t* {aka short unsigned int*}'".

It makes perfect sense but where to go from here?

The goal is to get the same result as with regular Arduino boards.

The library: https://github.com/mechasolution/Mecha_QMC5883

Comment: This sounds like a typical cross platform issue, sizes of integers are platform dependent (uint16_t is usually a unsigned short, but the size of it is implementation dependent, the standard only says it is at least 16 bit, so it should at least hold the value 65535. can you post a bit more about the code that is causing it? if you can prevent sending an int* and be more explicit it would probably solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because int on stm32 is 32bit and int on AVR is 16 bits long. When you pass pointer to int to the function which takes pointer to uint16_t there is no conversion possible. Why?

When you derefernce the pointer any asignments to the dereferanced one only write 2 bytes and the original type is 4 bytes. So 2 bytes are unaffected.

example

```
void foo(uint16_t *ptr) {
    *ptr = 0x1122
}

int val = 0x0feeddcc;

foo((uint16_t *)&val);
```

the result will be 0x0fee1122 not 0x00001122; -if you force it with the implicit cast. But it is an UB

Change int to short in your code to make them the same size.

another solution - leave int and unsigned not changed just rewrite the method;

```
#define PACKED __attribute__((__packed__))

void MechaQMC5883::read(int* x,int* y,int* z){
    PACKED union {
        short     xs;
        uint8_t   xu[2];
    }xunion;
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(address, 6);
  xunion.xu[0] = Wire.read(); 
  xunion.xu[1] = Wire.read(); 
  *x = (int)xunion.xs;
  xunion.xu[0] = Wire.read(); 
  xunion.xu[1] = Wire.read(); 
  *y = (int)xunion.xs;
  xunion.xu[0] = Wire.read(); 
  xunion.xu[1] = Wire.read(); 
  *z = (int)xunion.xs;
}
```

Comment: Even if they had the same number of bits, `uint16_t` still would be unsigned whereas plain `int` is signed.

Comment: On the byte level sign does not matter - in this function it is just the bunch of bits. Unsigned chars -> uint16_t, uint16_occupies the same space as int so when we read ir as int you will have the sign value. Side effects. Sensor send it as two bytes of the signed number. My changed function does it more elegant - more efficient way

Comment: It violates strict aliasing rules, and is Undefined Behavior. No diagnostic required (once you've silenced the compiler), but the compiler is under no obligation whatsoever to even emit code, let alone the code you expect.

Comment: @MSalters generally yes, practically no, as bare metal projects are using the particular compiler, toolchain and target hardware and the portability is not the issue here.

Comment: This worked as expected. Now code compiles and runs on STM32 and on  AVR with same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the conversion using a C style cast, and if the compiler moans about that, cast to a void * then to the desired type, and that will shut it up. But the complaints are very likely justified. int and uint16_t are probably not of the same width, so what do you expect to achieve by messing about with pointers in this manner?

Comment: This is actually bad advise, since a c-style cast will pick the 'best one', which means it could lead to a reinterpret cast, this is the same for void* casting tricks. for example reinterpreting a float as a double or int through reinterpret will not go well for you. It is better to figure out the actual issue and fix it correctly.

Comment: This is an UB for the reason described in my answer.

Comment: Correct answer. There's a possible cast, but that only silences the compiler. The complaint is indeed justified. It doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't *how* to convert, but *why*. The library wants an `uint16_t*`. So you shouldn't create an `int[N]`. Instead, create an `uint16_t[N]`, as the library expects.